# How to only display the legend keys of the biggest 8 proportions in bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar plot in ggplot2 and the columns all sum up to 1. However, there are 63 parts in each stack, if I show all legends keys in the plot, then it would take up too many spaces. How can I only display the legend keys of the biggest 8 proportions, and put all others to 'Others'?

[My dataset in pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/GEsJcgzw/), here I assume you input it as `Dataset`.

```
ggplot(Dataset,aes(Level,Value,group=Taxon,fill=Taxon))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~Site)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = diverge_hcl(63))+
    ylab("")+
    theme(
        legend.position = "none"
    )
```

[image]

And I want a legend like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we start with `Dataset0` read from your input file `Taxon_data.txt`

```r
library(colorspace)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

Dataset0 <- dget("Taxon_data.txt")

# Clean up labels: keep only the text after the underscore _
Dataset0 %<>% 
  mutate(Taxon = sub('.*\\_', '', Taxon)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Value))

# Create new factor "Tax" sorted by Value
Dataset0 %<>% 
  mutate(Site = factor(Site)) %>% 
  mutate(Tax = factor(Taxon, levels = unique(Taxon[order(-Value)])))

# Create labels for Legend
myLabel <- c(levels(Dataset0$Tax)[1:8], "Others",
             paste0("Others", 1:(length(unique(Dataset0$Tax)) - 9)))
myLabel

# Set myLabel for Tax, create new Dataset data frame
Dataset <- Dataset0 %>%
  mutate(Tax = factor(Tax, labels = myLabel))

# Setup colors
myColor <- c(brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"), 
             rep("lightblue3", length(unique(Dataset$Tax)) - 8))

# Plot

g1 <- ggplot(Dataset, aes(Level, Value, group=Tax, fill=Tax)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Site) +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend",
    breaks = c(levels(Dataset$Tax)[1:8], "Others"),
    values = myColor) +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14)
g1
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).